# How to send Ping frame from play framework server to websocket client and get pong Frame?

Tags: playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0

Using Play 2.4.x in Java.

I'm now in a project, that the websocket will need bidirection ping-pong via websocket, or the client will disconnect when timeout.

I'm using Actor way to handle websocket, and I cannot find ways to send ping frame with ActorRef directly.

Can any one has ideas?